# How to read multipart using Sring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, multipartform-data

I have the following in my controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "{storageId}/{repositoryId}", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public ResponseEntity uploadViaPost(@PathVariable(name = "storageId") String storageId,
                                    @PathVariable(name = "repositoryId") String repositoryId,
                                    @RequestPart("content")
                                    MultipartFile multipartFile,
                                    HttpServletRequest request)
            throws IOException
{
...
}
```

What classes/annotations do I need use, if I'd like to get the rest of the multi-part fields (which are not files)? Could somebody please provide an example of how to handle the rest of the fields such as:

```
----------------GHSKFJDLGDS7543FJKLFHRE75642756743254
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="platform"

UNKNOWN
----------------GHSKFJDLGDS7543FJKLFHRE75642756743254
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="version"

1.0
----------------GHSKFJDLGDS7543FJKLFHRE75642756743254
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"

UNKNOWN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple [`@RequestPart`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestPart.html) annotations in your method signature and annotating required data with `required=false` flag.

For example:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/test", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity testEndpoint(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file,
                                   @RequestPart("version") String version,
                                   @RequestPart(name = "platform", required = false) String platform) {
    log.info("file_name = {}, version = {}, platform = {}", file.getOriginalFilename(), version, platform);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();    
}
```

and curl for testing purposes:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/test \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F file=@/path/to/file/test.txt \
  -F version=1.0.0 \
  -F platform=Test-Platform
```

Comment: Oh, right! I didn't realize you can use the annotation on any kind of object. Thank you! :)

Comment: I don't think works. I'm getting `null`-s for these.

Comment: Interesting... If I replace these with just `@RequestParam`, they work fine. I was expecting that, as multi-part content, they would need to be annotated differently.